# User tools for managing services

Tags: java, apache-camel, soa, apache-servicemix

I have an application that consists of a number of services none of which have a user interface.  It struck me that in large applications that consist of possibly dozens of services that there would be a need for an administrator (not developer) to monitor, configure and start / stop services etc.  Is there a conventional approach for this?  One possibility would be for each service to have a separate management UI, but this would not be practical if hundreds of services were involved.  I assume that the best approach would be to have a single management service that communicated over a 'standard" API with each of the bespoke services - does this make sense?

Comment: Have you looked at the webconsole? http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/5.x/users-guide/web-console.html

Comment: Not so far - I will have a look.  I am really trying to understand the approaches that are used in large production systems.  I can't imagine that a "product" such as Linked in which would consists of dozens of services would not have a centralized management model for those services?